# Why I'am always getting "Duplicate Alert" error after doing update request?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension, vtiger, vtigercrm

I am writing Chrome Extension for Vtiger CRM.
I need to create ability to add value for "Proposal text" field in the CRM on project page.

Here is the docs: https://www.vtiger.com/docs/rest-api-for-vtiger#/Update

How I do it:

1. Get the project from Vtiger API.
2. Change value "cf_potentials_proposaltext" in the project object.
3. Make POST (as required by docs) request to update Vtiger API endpoint, send updated project object
4. Get "duplicate alert" response..

I am absolutely sure, since I checked that I am sending the modified project object - using the console.log 'Temprorary_1' (in vtigerAddProposal) and 'Temprorary_2'(in vtigerUpdatePotential), also checked changed value in Chrome dev console in Network tab..

Here is my code:

```
function vtigerAddProposal() {
    var temprorary_potential;
    var dialog = $('#dialog');

    chrome.storage.sync.get(['proposal'], function(result) {    
        $.ajax( {
            url: 'https://roonyx.od2.vtiger.com/restapi/v1/vtiger/default/retrieve',
            type: 'GET',
            data: {
                'id': localStorage.getItem('vtiger_last_opportunity_id')
            },
            success: function( response ) {
                temprorary_potential = response['result'];
                console.log("Temprorary_1: " + JSON.stringify(temprorary_potential, null, 2));
                temprorary_potential['cf_potentials_proposaltext'] = result.proposal;
                vtigerUpdatePotential(temprorary_potential);
            },
            error: function (response) {
                console.log("Failed to get opportunity from Vtiger.");
                $('#dialog-inner-text').text("Vtiger: " + response.status + " " + response.statusText);                    
                dialog.show(800);
                console.log(response);
            }
        });

    });
}

function vtigerUpdatePotential(data) {
    var dialog = $('#dialog');
    console.log("Temprorary_2: " + JSON.stringify(data, null, 2));

    // Second Part
    $.ajax( {
        url: 'https://roonyx.od2.vtiger.com/restapi/v1/vtiger/default/update',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
            element: JSON.stringify(data)
        },
        success: function( response ) {
            console.log("Successfully updated Vtiger potential.")
            console.log(response);
            localStorage.removeItem('vtiger_last_opportunity_id'); // в случае успеха удаляем oppId
        },
        error: function (response) {
            console.log("Failed to update potential in Vtiger.")
            $('#dialog-inner-text').text("Vtiger potential wasn't update: " + response.status + " " + response.statusText);                    
            dialog.show(800);
            console.log(response);
        }
    });
}
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Is it possible to post the data object here? Also, can you try using revise https://www.vtiger.com/docs/rest-api-for-vtiger#/Revise once instead of update?

Comment: Thank you. That solves the problem

Comment: great, please post it as an answer and accept so it can help anyone else having the same issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved by using revise https://www.vtiger.com/docs/rest-api-for-vtiger#/Revise once instead of update. Thanks to @pinaki